# graphql - querying multiple tables

Tags: graphql

I am new to graphql and I need to query multiple tables at once to display some data. I have a dashboard that shows information on a home where it comes from 5 tables: address, person, hostinfo, room, and image. I initially have the `person_id` to query `address` table which contains the `person_id` etc... Here's what a brief scratch up of a uml looks like:

```
entity Address {
    AddressId BigInteger,
    FK_PersonId BigInteger,
    StreetNumber Integer,
    ...
}

entity HostInfo {
    HostInfoId BigInteger,
    FK_AddressId BigInt,
    HomestayName String,
    ...
}

entity Room {
    RoomId BigInteger,
    FK_HostInfoId BigInteger,
    RoomName String,
    ...
}

entity Image {
    FK_AddressId BigInt,
    FK_RoomID BigInt,
    Name String,
    ....
}

entity Person {
    PersonId,
    FirstName String,
    Age Integer required, //TODO remember to check age
}
```

My question is, how do I use graphql to grab all the data from these tables using just `PersonId`?
EDIT--------
I refactored the typedefiniton as follows:

```
    export type Address = {
      StreetNumber: number,
      //..
      Person:Person
    }

    export type HostInfo = {
      HomestayName: string,
      //..
      Person:Person,
      Room:[Room!],
      Address:Address
    }

    export type Room = {
      RoomName: string,
      //..
      RoomImage:[RoomImage!],
      HostInfo:HostInfo
    }

    export type RoomImage = {
      Name: string,
      //..
      Room:Room,
    }

    export type HostInfoImage = {
      Name: string,
      ..
      HostInfo:HostInfo
    }

    export type PersonImage = {
      Name: string,
      //..
      Person:Person
    }

export type Person = {
  FirstName: string,
  ..
  PersonImage:[PersonImage]
  Address:Address
}
```

and perform the query as so:

```
query HostInfo($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on Person {
      firstName
      address {
        streetNumber
        hostInfo {
            HostName,
            //...
            Room {
                RoomName,
               [RoomImage],
               //....
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would explicitly show the relationship both ways in my entities... I was expecting more of a sql(ly) way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically GraphQL would represent all of the links between objects explicitly in the schema: if in your database model an `Address` references a `Person`, then your `Person` GraphQL type would have a list of addresses.  In the GraphQL schema language, you might have:

```
type Person implements Node {
  id: ID!,
  firstName: String,
  age: Int!,
  address: [Address!]!
}
```

If you knew the ID of a person, a typical query to retrieve much of the available data might hypothetically look like

```
query Person($id: ID!) {
  node(id: $id) {
    ... on Person {
      firstName
      age
      address {
        streetNumber
        hostInfo { ... }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, why would Person have an array of addresses in the specification? As I need it, person would have a 1 to 1 reference to address.

Comment: In the schema in the original question, there could be multiple addresses with the same `FK_PersonId`, which would create a one-to-many relationship, where one person could have several addresses.  If a `Person` only has one `Address` then the GraphQL schema can reflect that.